# Students name converted with ","?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I have string value of some of the names of students, name converted into an array.
Separate all the students name by **","**
I have string:

```
String str = "Arjun,Loren,Streesh,Novel,Ducks,John,Ranbinson,Ducket,Stifen,Jonny,Anil,Junos";
```

Comment: use `split` . `str.split(',');`. Your question is not clear. What output you want and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your tags suggest that you want server-side code in e.g. C#, but jQuery runs as javascript in the browser. These are two completely different things. Please [edit] the question to be more clear about what you want and where the code should run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps:

1. you have to split the string by ',' using C# and store in the string array.
2. Use the foreach loop with the string array inserts the data into the database.

   ```
   String str = "Arjun,Loren,Streesh,Novel,Ducks,John,Ranbinson,Ducket,Stifen,Jonny,Anil,Junos";
   String[] strArray = str.Split(',');

   foreach (object obj in strArray)
   {
   //insert query
   }
   ```

Comment: `var[]` is not C#... And why use `object obj` in the loop when you have `string`s...

Comment: Thank you so much and I will got answer before in comment section.